# x-axis tiks label is showing separately

Tags: pgfplots, axis

How to change the x-axis ticks of the plot to scientific notation? As of now the `$$.10^4$$` is showing separately as marked in the red box.

[image]

**Code:**

```
\documentclass[tikz, border=1cm]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.18}

% 3N5H_test.csv
\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \pgfplotsset{
          set layers,% using layers
          mark layer=axis tick labels,% defines the layer of the marks
          every axis/.append style={scale=0.8}
        }
        \begin{semilogyaxis}[ xmin=0, xmax=0.1e5,
                             ymin=1e-4, ymax=1,
                             xlabel={Number of Flops}, 
                             ylabel={Normalized MSE: $\log_{10} (e)$ },
                             scatter/classes={ a={mark=square*, blue}, b={mark=square*, red}, c={mark=square, black}, d={mark=triangle*, blue}, e={mark=triangle*, red},f={mark=triangle*, black},g={mark=x, black}, h={mark= diamond*, pink} },
                                    ] 
                                    \addplot[scatter, only marks,
                                    scatter src=explicit symbolic]
                                    table[meta=label] {
                                        x     y      label
                                        1320.9279232530525 0.06258769833615981 a
                                        };
                                    \addplot[scatter, only marks,
                                    scatter src=explicit symbolic]
                                    table[meta=label] {
                                        x     y      label
                                        7320.9279232530525 0.002258769833615981 b
                                        };
        \end{semilogyaxis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Please make your MWE compilable. Missed are tables with data used in your diagram.

Comment: @Zarko , thanks for the comment. I hope now the MWE works fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `xticklabel style` to set the style of the labels on the *x*-axis. `/pgf/number format/sci` changes each label number into scientific notation, and `scaled ticks=false` ensures that the scientific notation exponent isn't floating to the bottom-right like it is in your original graph. Because scientific notation takes up a lot of space, I've taken the liberty of rotating your *x*-labels so that they're easier to read.

```tex
\documentclass[border=1cm]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.18}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \pgfplotsset{
          set layers,% using layers
          mark layer=axis tick labels,% defines the layer of the marks
          every axis/.append style={scale=0.8}
        }
        \begin{semilogyaxis}[
            xmin=0, xmax=0.1e5,
            ymin=1e-4, ymax=1,
            xlabel={Number of Flops}, 
            ylabel={Normalized MSE: $\log_{10} (e)$ },
            scatter/classes={
                a={mark=square*, blue},
                b={mark=square*, red},
                c={mark=square, black},
                d={mark=triangle*, blue},
                e={mark=triangle*, red},
                f={mark=triangle*, black},
                g={mark=x, black},
                h={mark= diamond*, pink}
            },
            xticklabel style={
                /pgf/number format/sci,
                scaled ticks = false,
                rotate = 90
            }
        ] 
        \addplot[scatter, only marks,scatter src=explicit symbolic]
            table[meta=label] {
                x     y      label
                1320.9279232530525 0.06258769833615981 a
            };
        \addplot[scatter, only marks,scatter src=explicit symbolic]
            table[meta=label] {
                x     y      label
                7320.9279232530525 0.002258769833615981 b
            };
        \end{semilogyaxis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: A semilogarithmic graph of two data points. The y-axis is logarithmic, and the x-axis is linear. The x-axis is in scientific notation from zero to ten thousand, and each x-axis label is rotated 90 degrees counterclockwise.]